# Invalid cursor state of ODBC plugin in dolphindb

Tags: dolphindb

Invalid cursor state of  ODBC plugin in dolphindb

I use ODBC plugin and connect sql server successfully.

```
conn = odbc::connect("DSN=testjob;Uid=SA;Pwd=Password1;")
```

But when I query table test from database Test1,

```
odbc::query(conn,"use Test1; select * from test")
```

it raise an error:

```
odbc/src/nanodbc.cpp:3025: 2400: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid cursor state
```

What's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the table test contains a field type that dolphindb cannot recognize.
You can use the following statement:

```py
odbc::query(conn,"use Test1; select columnName from test")
```

Check which field cannot be loaded, and then load it by modifying the field type (the field type supported by dolphindb).